# Data Export Import modules total nodes storage limit problem

Tags: importing-exporting

I import Mysql into Drupal 7 site using [Data Export Import.](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import)

The progressing importing showing error message:

> Processed 263 (0 created, 0 updated, 263 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.8
>   sec (568/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 260 (0 created, 0 updated, 260 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.3
>   sec (571/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 258 (0 created, 0 updated, 258 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.5
>   sec (564/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 253 (0 created, 0 updated, 253 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.5
>   sec (552/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'
>
> Processed 255 (0 created, 0 updated, 255 failed, 0 ignored) in 27.4
>   sec (558/min) - continuing with '1cf4f3dbbFile'

When it finished running, the nodes are not completely imported. Only 20-30% nodes are imported.

My Drupal 6 has 110,000 nodes. Would it cause the error?

Because I saw this information in the module note.

[This release has been heavily tested on a Drupal 6 environment. Nodes with up to 140MB of attached files were exported and re-imported](https://www.drupal.org/node/1836530)

If it is the problem to cause the error, how should I increase the nodes storage?

Comment: "This release has been heavily tested on a Drupal 6 environment. Nodes with up to 140MB of attached files were exported and re-imported" - This refers to the total size of the files that were attached to **a single node**, not the sum of all nodes. Are you importing nodes with files attached by any chance?

Comment: No. I just import the mysql database and some error above shown. Do you know what is the command-line for drush to import and export the nodes?

Comment: Jason: Drush - that is a separate question, probably found easily with a search. As for your import, you are using the module in a way that isn't recommended (migrate 6 > 7) so I doubt anyone here can help you. You can try posting in the module's issue queue, but they may tell you the same thing. Sorry I can't be more help. Cheers -